# stageInitS4sdkPipeline running on slave node not working anymore

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, sap-cloud-sdk

[My Requirements] I have setup pipeline with master node and multiple slave nodes. Since my master node does not have web access to github.com, so I need to transfer all pipeline workload to slave nodes.

[Previous configuration, failed now]
1. Configuration in Jenkinsfile

```
pipeline {
    agent { node { label 'slave1' } }
```

2. Modification of cloud-s4-sdk-pipeline-lib/vars/stageInitS4sdkPipeline.groovy

```
    node('slave1') {
        deleteDir()
```

```
    [Current Error message] When running initS4sdkPipeline, it changes back to master node
    10:24:37  + `date --utc +%Y-%m-%dT%H%M%S%Z`
    [Pipeline] `echo`
    10:24:37  [artifactSetVersion] Sending telemetry data is disabled.
    [Pipeline] `node`
    10:24:38  Running on Jenkins in /var/jenkins_home/workspace/PipelineJava_master
    [Pipeline] {
    [Pipeline] }
    [Pipeline] `// node`
    [Pipeline] `echo`
    10:24:38  --- Begin library step of: mavenExecute ---
    [Pipeline] `echo`
    10:24:38  Unstash content: piper-bin
    [Pipeline] unstash
    [Pipeline] `echo`
    10:24:38  Unstash failed: piper-bin (No such saved stash ‘piper-bin’)
    [Pipeline] httpRequest
    10:24:38  HttpMethod: GET
    10:24:38  URL: https://github.com/SAP/jenkins-library/releases/download/v1.39.0/piper
    10:24:38  Sending request to url: https://github.com/SAP/jenkins-library/releases/download/v1.39.0/piper
    10:24:38  Treating UnknownHostException(github.com: Name or service not known) as 404 Not Found
```

[further questions] I never understand why it is hard coded as node('master') in stageInitS4sdkPipeline. I think it is much better if it is configurable using node label names. Currently, I also do not have clues for how this will support multiple slave nodes distribution. And There is more steps are hard coded in pipeline, for example: 'checkDiskSpace.groovy'

Answer (score 1):

I think this specific issue was resolved in version v36 of the SAP Cloud Sdk Pipeline by not using curl anymore and not forcing to run parts of the init stage on the master.

For more details please also see the release notes of v36
https://github.com/SAP/cloud-s4-sdk-pipeline/releases/tag/v36